# Synchronous MQ call using ibmmq and TypeScript

Tags: typescript, ibm-mq, synchronous

First off, I am a total noob at typescript and have some knowledge of mq plus the solution I am wanting to implement will be thrown out in a years time so a ‘good enough’ solution will do.

What I want to be able to do is make a synchronous to MQ call using ibmmq and TypeScript. I have played around with various samples and have successfully put a message on a queue (this was after writing a small java app using MQQueueConnectionFactory) but have no idea how to pick up and/or read the response.

What I have working (I think) is as follows:

```
    mq.ConnxPromise(qMgr, cno)
        .then((hConn) => {
            logger.info("a) MQCONN to %s successful ", qMgr);
            ghConn = hConn;
            const od = new mq.MQOD();
            od.ObjectName = qName;
            od.ObjectType = MQC.MQOT_Q;
            const openOptions = MQC.MQOO_OUTPUT;
            return mq.OpenPromise(hConn, od, openOptions);
        })
        .then((hObj) => {
            logger.info("b) MQOPEN of %s successful", qName);

            const mqmd = new mq.MQMD(); // Defaults are fine.
            const pmo = new mq.MQPMO();
            // Describe how the Put should behave
            pmo.Options = MQC.MQPMO_NO_SYNCPOINT | MQC.MQPMO_NEW_MSG_ID | MQC.MQPMO_NEW_CORREL_ID;

            ghObj = hObj;
            const response = mq.PutPromise(hObj, mqmd, pmo, message);
            return response;
        })
        .then(() => {
            logger.info("MQPUT successful");"your text"
            return mq.ClosePromise(ghObj, 0);
        })
        .then(() => {
            logger.info("MQCLOSE successful");
            return mq.DiscPromise(ghConn);
        })
        .then(() => {
            logger.info("Done.");
        })
```

Keep in mind I am a typescript noob so would appreciate a spelled out answer rather than "oh, you simply need to disengage the Heisenberg  Compensators" would be appreciated.

Comment: For synchronous get take a look at this amqsget sample https://github.com/ibm-messaging/mq-mqi-nodejs/blob/master/samples/amqsget.js

Answer (score 0):

If you really want to do synchronous work, then *GetSync* would the function to call. (And all the other Promise functions in your program could be replaced by the Sync equivalents.) But read the notes about how *GetSync* blocks anything else from happening - fine if you don't set it in a Get-Wait mode, but not so good for your program otherwise. Get doesn't really map to a promise invocation.

Look at the samples in the repo that demonstrate different ways to get messages. amqsget.js is the one doing synchronous work; amqsgeta*.js do it async.